# A control that is equivalent to the "Properties Window" of Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls, propertygrid

I say, as in the picture:

[image]

if not exists, how to create it dynamically?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is called the [PropertyGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid.aspx) control in WinForms.

There are also various WPF implementations:

- [WPF Property Grid](http://wpg.codeplex.com/)
- [WPF PropertyGrid Control](http://wpfpropertygrid.codeplex.com/)
- [Native WPF 4 PropertyGrid](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/WpfPropertyGrid.aspx)

And at least one Silverlight implementation:

- [PropertyGrid - Silverlight 3.0](http://slg30.codeplex.com/)

And finally, at least one for ASP.Net:

- [ASP.Net PropertyGrid](http://propertygrid.codeplex.com/)