# .NET Core 3.0 "System.String constructor not found error" When Trying to modify a string[] from a propertyGrid

Tags: c#, forms, propertygrid, asp.net-core-3.0

I have an option class looking like this:

```
public class FooOptions
{
    [Description("string"), DefaultValue("foo")]
    public string Foo { get; set; }

    [Description("Array of strings"), DefaultValue(new[] { "foo" })]
    public string[] FooArray { get; set; }   

    //...
}
```

I modify it through a PropertyGrid ([System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.propertygrid?view=netcore-3.0)).

Everything used to work fine until I switched from .NET Framework to .NET Core 3.0.

When I click on the FooArray option in the PropertyGrid, the String Collection Editor window pops up as before:
[image]

but when I try to add a new value, I get the following error "Constructor on type 'System.String' not found".

I tried to specify an editor via the component model (as advised by many articles):

```cs
[Editor("System.Windows.Forms.Design.StringCollectionEditor, System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", "System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor")]
public string[] FooArray { get; set; }
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: What GUI framework are you using?  [`System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGrid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.propertygrid?view=netcore-3.1)?  Something else from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8844947) or elsewhere?

Comment: The full exception stack trace, please.

Comment: StringCollectionEditor doesn't exist in .NET Core 3.0, you need .NET Core 3.1: https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/pull/1284 upgrade your project's target to .NET Core 3.1 and it will behave just like in .NET framework.

Comment: I applied @Simon solution and it works fine. Thank you! (tell me if I need to answer the question and accept it or do anything to close it)

Comment: If you're happy, you can answer yourself and get some points

Comment: A List<string> does not work. It has to be string[]. And the editor that shows up is a free-text, where newline is what determines a new entry. Not the greatest, but I guess it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StringCollectionEditor doesn't exist in .NET Core 3.0.
I upgraded my project's target to .NET Core 3.1 and it behaves like in .NET framework.